# How do you reply to a message from "Replies" chat (Telethon)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telethon

### Problem

My "userbot" leaves comments on new posts from channels

Some users reply to my comments, those replies appear in my "Replies" dialog

I want to reply back to those replies, but I get same error

```sh
telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist.YouBlockedUserError: You blocked this user (caused by SendMessageRequest)
```

I don't have any users in the black list

### Code

This my message handler

```py
# id of "Replies" dialog 
replies_chat_id = 1271266957

async def handle_message(event: events.NewMessage.Event):
    # handle msg from "replies" chat (problem is here)
    if (event.chat_id == replies_chat_id):
        # just send 'ok' to everyone who replied to my comment
        await event.client.send_message(message="ok", entity=event.chat_id, reply_to=event.message)
    # handle msg from channel (it works fine)
    elif (event._broadcast):
        # just leave a comment on post
        await event.client.send_message(message="ok", entity=event.chat_id, comment_to=event.message)
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading about [Threads](https://core.telegram.org/api/threads) I've managed to solve the problem

```py
await event.client.send_message(
  entity = event.message.reply_to.reply_to_peer_id, 
  reply_to = event.message.fwd_from.saved_from_msg_id, 
  message = 'ok'
)
```